# How to fix Error: socket hang up in Postman & testing Laravel 9 API

Tags: laravel, postman

When creating an API and testing it, I get the following error message for a Route:Register within Postman: Error: socket hang up

But I can't see any error in the source code.
What can be the reason for this?

http://localhost:8000/api/register

[Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt6Vx.png)

api.php

```php
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

// Public Routes
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'register']);
Route::get('/products', [ProductController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/products/search/{name}', [ProductController::class, 'search']);
Route::get('/products/{$id}', [ProductController::class, 'show($id)']);

// Protected Routes
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function() {
    Route::post('/products', [ProductController::class, 'store']);
    Route::put('/products/{$id}', [ProductController::class, 'update ']);
    Route::delete('/products/{$id}', [ProductController::class, 'delete']);
});


//
// Route::post('/products', [ProductController::class, 'store']);
// ;
```

AuthController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request) {
        $fields = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|unique:users,email',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $fields['name'],
            'email' => $fields['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($fields['password'])
        ]);

        $token = $user->createToken('myapptoken')->plainTextToken;

        $response = [
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token
        ];

        return response($response, 201);
    }
}
```

php artisan serve is running When i un-check the keys in the body @postman, i get:

```json
{ "message": "The name field is required. (and 2 more errors)", "errors": { "name": [ "The name field is required." ], "email": [ "The email field is required." ], "password": [ "The password field is required." ] } }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sU3u.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzPIK.png)

Comment: Did you start the server? (php artisan serve)

Comment: please add your api and controller code so we can find the error

Comment: sure, the server is started. @JorgePérez

Comment: Code is added @MohammadEdrisRaufi

Comment: I deleted my own answer to avoid confusions, since I tried to reproduce the problem and the code (SyncMasta original code) ran as expected (no errors) with both Insomnia and Postman. Could you share a screenshot of your request Headers? (i see you included that in your imgur screenshot but you show only one and we need to see the others to analyze). @SyncMasta

Comment: @JorgePérez I have added the pictures

Comment: Thank you. Everything seems in order so far. What's your php version? e.g. mine is 8.1.10. Another idea: Have you tried recreating the single postman request from scratch and deleting cookies,

Comment: thx, problem solved with restart postman

Comment: You are welcome . I posted as answer so you can choose as correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works perfectly.
Recreate the single postman request from scratch and deleting cookies.

[Some related literature on why rebooting systems help.](https://www.howtogeek.com/173760/htg-explains-why-does-rebooting-a-computer-fix-so-many-problems/)